# JMeter Webdriver waittime issue

Tags: jmeter, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a scenario where I need to click on a button in the Web page which will do a process. Once I click on this button "process in progress" message will appear. I am waiting for this message to disappear from the web page for the next action.

This process will take time between 30 to 150 secs which I don't have control.So I have given a wait time of 180 secs in the sampler. The issue is some time the process will complete in 30 secs and webdriver will wait for 180 secs to complete for the next action. In this case application will log out because inactive user settings.

How to handle this situation?

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to community. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated** combined with **WebDriverWait**.

It would wait at max 150s but if element is available before it doesn't wait that much:

```
 var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 150);
 wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
         pkg.By.cssSelector('ul.suggestions')))
```

See full details here:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/

Answer (score 0):

You can go for [ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) function which can be used via [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) so WebDriver will poll the DOM until the element disappears with the maximum of 150 seconds, default polling interval is 500 milliseconds, however it [can be adjusted](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#pollingEvery-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) as required.

Example code would be something like:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 150)
wait.pollingEvery(1, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text('process in progress')]"))
```

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)